# Find first column text in current row

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm not sure if there's an exception because I'm working with Knockout, or not, but I can't seem to get the first column's text value.

When I click on a button in a row, I am trying to get the first cell's text associated with that row, NOT including headers (just the ID field).

Here's my basic HTML.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center" id="plan_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
            <th>
                # of Payouts
            </th>
            <th>
                Edit
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: paymentOption">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: paymentQuantity"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reroute()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what I am trying (along with any solution found on StackOverflow)...

```
function reroute() {
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    //$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();
    console.log(name);
}
```

Every single time I get an empty string, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `onclick` attribute, you should pass `this` (event caller) to the method:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reroute(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
```

Script:

```
function reroute(el) {
    var name = $(el).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    //$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();
    console.log(name);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srndhvv7/)

---

I would however make it [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) if that's possible

```
<button class="btn btn-default my-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
```

Script:

```
$('.my-btn').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    //$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ma4qdms/)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Can you explain why my solution wasn't working by any chance? Or why the `onclick` makes a difference here? I appreciate it!

Comment: Your solution wasn't working because you didn't pass the event caller (the button element - `this`) in `onclick` attribute. Therefore inside the `reroute()` function, `$(this)` is not related to the *button* but to the `window` (as the function is in global scope). As for the `onclick` attribute itself and why it's *mostly* better to not hang scripts like that on the elements, you can read in the link I have posted.

Comment: Thanks! I will read up on it. Again, I appreciate your help/time.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be scraping data from HTML when you use Knockout. Your button has access to the row data (conveniently enough, in $data).

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="reroute($data.Id)">
```

should pass the data you want to your reroute function.

I have created a fiddle that works. There were a number of details that needed to be handled in a Knockout fashion.
http://jsfiddle.net/srndhvv7/1/

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. I tried your solution, AND.. `$data.Id()`, `Id()` `paymentOption.Id` `paymentOption.Id()`.. All said `$data` or `paymentOption` aren't defined. (I'm new to Knockout)

Comment: See the fiddle I have attached.

Comment: I'm thinking `$root` (since it refers to the parent, view model object) is the reason your fiddle works and within my app it doesn't. I'll give you an upvote, and I do appreciate your time/effort.

Comment: Correct: everything you refer to in a data-bind has to be a member of your viewmodel (or a member-of-a-member, etc.). This should not present an obstacle to getting your program to work.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is presenting an obstacle so much as my inexperience with Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function reroute() {
    var name = $(".table").find('td:first-child').text();
    console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: For sake of completeness because Artur solved my problem, I went ahead and test your solution. Your solution yields the results : `10AN40QTLS`.. Which is the entire first column. I just wanted the column for the row I am on. I appreciate your effort though!

Comment: To be honest with you I didn't test my code and you're right it returns the entire column I have tested it now thank you for letting me know best way to do is how artur did